# Trouble getting JSON DeserializeObject to work on this class

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to deserialize the following class using Json.Net and receiving the error:

> Error converting value "abc" to type 'System.UInt16'. Path 'typestr'

```
public class TestClass 
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public static ushort TEST_TYPE_A = 0;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public static ushort TEST_TYPE_B = 1;

    [JsonProperty("typestr")]
    public string typestr {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty("testvalue")]
    public string testvalue {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty("bob")]
    public string bob {get; set;}

    public TestClass(ushort typestr)
    {
        this.typestr = types[typestr];
    }

    public void Init() { }
}


TestClass a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>("{\"typestr\": \"abc\"}");
```

Does anyone know how to get around this error?

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't throw that exception - at least not on my machine using Json.NET v10.0.3. My guess is that you've tried to copy your real code into a short but complete example (which is good) but without checking that it reproduces the problem (which is bad). Please provide a genuine [mcve].

Comment: Updated declaration of the constructor which makes it error now.

Comment: Well that's *very* confusing to start with - accepting a `ushort` called `typestr` but also having a `string` property called `typestr`. Presumably Json.NET is trying to call the constructor, but you've given it a string instead of a `ushort`. Can't you avoid that type collision? Even just renaming the parameter may be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've provided JSON with a property of `typestr` which has a string value. You've also got two parts called `typestr` in your class:

- A property (type `string`)
- A constructor parameter (type `ushort`)

Json.NET could use either of those, but apparently the constructor parameter takes precedence - which makes some sense given that you haven't provided any other constructors.

You can:

- Change the name of the constructor parameter
- Provide a parameterless constructor

Either of those seems to do the trick - I would personally provide a parameterless constructor if you don't expect the JSON values to be used in the constructor call.